# WP7 and Basic Authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, windows-phone-7, webclient

I am trying to use thew WebClient (have tried HttpWebRequest as well) to call a SSL protected api on  a web site that required Basic Authentication, but am getting an exception being thrown  in the DownloadStringAsync callback.  Here is my code, in this case calling Twitter:

```
    private void Button_Click2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

        webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadStringCompleted);
        NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
        webClient.Credentials = credentials;
        webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(@"http://twitter.com/statuses/friends_timeline.xml"));
    }

    void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e) 
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("e.Error: " + e.Error);    
    }
```

As I mentioned am getting an exception being thrown with the text below

{"The remote server returned an error: NotFound."}

It would appear from reading various postings that the WebClient is not sending the credentials, I have also tried the following :

```
        string authInfo = "username:password";
        authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(StringToAscii(authInfo));

        webClient.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + authInfo;
```

But with the same results, any pointers on what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated, as I am tearing my hear out over this one.

BTW I have tried the above code with a call that does not require authentication and that works OK, have also tried the code in a WPF project and again it works, it is just in the WP7 emulator that it fails.

Thanks in advance,
Rupert.

Comment: Try hooking up Fiddler and seeing what's going on in terms of actual message being sent out: http://phone7.wordpress.com/2010/10/17/fiddler-and-wp7-emulator-working/

Comment: +1 for Alastair; that's where I would start. There is a difference between what the emulator is requesting as opposed to your WPF mockup. It could point to a bug in the emulator worth logging on MS Connect. I know it wasn't all that reliable when I first tried to use it a few months ago.

Answer (score 1):

Callbacks for the `WebClient` are marshalled onto the UI thread, so you may want to use `HttpWebRequest` instead to avoid blocking the UI thread and adversing affecting the perceived performance of your application. That said, when I run a version of your code that uses `HttpWebRequest` the response I get from the server is as follows:

```
<errors>
  <error code="53">Basic authentication is not supported</error> 
</errors>
```

This is because Twitter have stopped supporting basic authentication (no doubt for security reasons) and now only support OAUTH.

Dan Booth has a useful [blog post](http://www.diplo.co.uk/blog/2010/8/9/oauth-with-twitter.aspx) that describes how to use OAUTH with Twitter and includes examples of using the [Hammock](http://hammock.codeplex.com) REST library. You may also want to consider using a Tiwtter library such as [TweetSharp](http://tweetsharp.codeplex.com/) to save you time and effort.